# Count number of not null rows column wise in a txt file in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am trying to count the number of not null rows of all column in a txt file. I am able to read not null rows in each column individually but I am trying to loop them all together. `awk - F "|" '$1!=""{N++} print N'`

Here is a look at my data

A | B | C | D | E

1 | 2 | 0 | 8 |

5 | 3 | 6 |    | 4

|    | 8 |    |

| 7 | 8 |    |

8 | 9 | 2 |    | 4

I want the result to be like :
Column A: 3
Column B: 4
Column C: 5
Column D: 1
Column E: 2

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is not working. Please remove the space between `- F` and call `print N` at the end using `END` :

```
awk -F "|" '$1!=""{N++} END {print N}' input.txt
```

This command will also count lines with some text missing a `|`.
An alternative would be

```
grep -cE "[^|]+\|" input.txt
```

Comment: Yes you are right and thanks for your correction. But it counts only for the first column. I want to loop it for 'N' columns

Comment: I am not sure what you want. When you want to dismiss all lines starting or ending with `|`, and the lines with `||`, try `grep -vcE "^\||\|\||\|$" input.txt` (first check `grep -vE`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all columns of all lines, instead of a particular column:

```
awk -F'|' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i != "") n++ } END { print n }' input.txt
```

For each line, loop over every `|`-delimited field in that line, incrementing a counter if it's not empty. Finally print the count at the end.

Comment: This will provide not null values linewise but I want it column wise for all the columns.

Comment: @MdDanishKhan You're going to have to provide examples in your question to better explain what you want then.

Comment: I have added an example. Hope it might help.